# How to manually add Items to MultiSelect in react-selectize?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, selectize.js

I'm trying to add new value to react-selectize multiselect when the user clicks on a button (I use http://furqanzafar.github.io/react-selectize/#/) .

In JQuery I just call addItem(value, silent) on a button click.

for example in JQuery:

```
v.selectize.addItem("email@gmail.com");
```

**In My code:**

**I created some MultiSelect component:**

```
<MultiSelect
        placeholder = "All Emails"
        options = {this.state.emails.map(
          source => ({label: source, value: source})
        )}
        onValuesChange = {value => this.onInputChange(value, "sources")}
/>
```

**Then I have this button on the bottom of the page:**

```
<button OnClick={this.addEmailValue("email@gmail.com")}></button>
```

**When I click on the button it goes to:**

```
addEmailValue(email){
    //here I want to add the email as a item to the multiSelect
}
```

**How can I add "email@gmail.com" to the MultiSelect as an item? (just like the JQuery example on top)**

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Your question needs some work so the community can better help you. Take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and give it another try.

Comment: It's better now? :)

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with React but in other frameworks like Vue you would push the new email to your array the multiselect is getting as its source. IE: `addEmailValue(email) { state.emails.push(email); }`

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of things, you just need to update the 'emails' state by pushing the new email to it in your addEmailValue function. For instance:

```
addEmailValue(email) {
   var emails = this.state.emails;

   emails.push({
      label: email,
      value: email
   });

   this.setState({
      emails: emails
   });
}
```